# SMS mark as Read using AT Command in USB Modem

Tags: vb.net, sms, at-command

I am using Globe Broadband Stick and developing a VB.net application that can send and receive messages. For now i can send and receive SMS but the problem i have is i cannot Mark unread messages as Read.

This is what i did:

```
SerialPortX.Write("AT+CMGL=""ALL""" & vbCrLf)
```

but still when i tried to execute this command

```
SerialPortX.Write("AT+CMGL=""REC UNREAD""" & vbCrLf)
```

I still see the unread messages.

I also tried to do one on one reading using AT+CMGR=  but still it doesnt change message status.